# How to get the schema of DolphinDB table through the Java API

Tags: dolphindb

I get the schema by following the code:

```
val schema = conn.run("schema(table)").asInstanceOf[BasicDictionary]
```

But how do I get the schema out of it.

Comment: Hi, your question is not clear, could you please edit your post and make it more precise ? (I'm saying that especially because you are saying that you do get the schema ...)

Comment: I want to get the scheme of dolphindb table through that code